# How to setup a test environment (test gem`s + test database)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, bundler, azk

It's my first time using azk in my development (Ruby 2.2.3 + Rails 4 project)

I want run the Rspec tests.

How I use Azkfile to create a specific system to test environment? (test gem's + test database + webkit dependencies)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's advisable to share the code you currently have, and ask a specific question about it in order to get the best from the community.

Answer (score 2):

Add the systems `test` and`postgres-test` to your Azkfile.js as example below.

To run the provision you must use the start and then stop the system:

```
$ azk start -R test && azk stop test
$ azk shell -- bundle exec rspec spec
```

Or you can run the provision commands directly in the shell:

```
$ azk start postgres-test

$ azk shell test
bundle install --path /azk/bundler
bundle exec rake db:create
bundle exec rake db:migrate

$ azk shell -- bundle exec rspec spec
```

## Example:

```
systems({
  app: {
    // ..
  },
  postgres: {
    // ...
  },

  /* TEST */
  test: {
    extends: "app",
    depends: ["postgres-test"],
    command: "bundle exec rspec spec && exit 0",
    provision: [
      "bundle install --path /azk/bundler",
      "bundle exec rake db:create",
      "bundle exec rake db:migrate",
    ],
    scalable: { default: 0, limit: 1 },
    http: false,
    wait: false,
    envs: {
      RAILS_ENV: "test",
      RACK_ENV : "test",
      BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG: "/azk/bundler",
      HOST: "#{system.name}.#{azk.default_domain}",
    },
  },
  "postgres-test": {
    extends: "postgres",
    scalable: { default: 0, limit: 1 },
    envs: {
      // set instances variables
      POSTGRES_USER: "azk",
      POSTGRES_PASS: "azk",
      POSTGRES_DB  : "#{manifest.dir}_test",
    },
  },
});
```